# How to differenciate different user's contact list in "names.nsf" of Domino Server?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am accessing contacts of all user's from Domino server.
But contacts of all user's are saved on single file ("names.nsf") and i want to display it user wise.

Can anybody tell me how to differentiate contact list of different user's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

names.nsf on the server should be your corporate address book. Individual users should not have access to write to this file.

Each user should also have a names.nsf on their local install. If they are a roaming user, this might be copied up to the server under their roaming user profile. That is the only time you'd see it on the server. But it doesn't overwrite, or in any other way interact with, the server's names.nsf. They have different replicaIDs. This database has a field "

Users can replicate the server's names.nsf down if they work disconnected, but it should be set up with a different filename, or in a different folder, so that it doesn't overwrite their personal names.nsf. Again, it will have a different replicaID, so it won't interact with their personal names.nsf.

The two databases have different design templates as well.

It is also possible to set up one or more shared address books via Directory Assistance. These types of address books can be custom developed in-house, and are often used by groups of people. For instance, a purchasing department might have an address book of the vendor contacts. The only way I can think of to tell them apart would be $UpdatedBy, unless the dev who created this database added a field to record the entry owner.